# Zabbix is unable to set "Content-type: application/json" HTTP header

Tags: zabbix

I'm trying to make a web scenario that will test login page. I checked this using Fiddler and in POST which is sent is added to the **"Content-type: application/json"** HTTP header you can not do in a web scenario Zabbix 2.2.1 if anyone could me how to solve this problem., Or maybe there is some other mechanism or whether it is possible to implement this in zabbixie 2.2.1

Please give me some advice

Regards
Mick

Answer (score 2):

Zabbix 2.4 introduces support for custom headers in Web scenarios (see [What's new in Zabbix 2.4](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/introduction/whatsnew240#ability_to_specify_custom_headers)), so you might wish to upgrade your installation.

Comment: I cannot use zabbix 2.4 I must do this on 2.2.1

Comment: Same. Its what we're at. However, at this point, upgrading is what needs to happen.